# Trying to understand exceptional divisors and Du Val singularities.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, blowup

I'v been trying to understand how Du Val singularities are resolved and what the exceptional divisors look like so I can work out their dynkin diagrams. A basic example I tried in the interest of getting some intuition was $z^2+y(x+y^2)=0$. First blow it up with coordinates $[x_0:y_0:z_0]$ and let $x_0=1$ so $y=xy_0$ , $z=xz_0$ to so we should get one of the affine charts $(xz_0)^2+xy_0(x+(xy_0)^2)=0$,

$\implies x^2(z_0^2+y_0+xy_0^3)=0$

My understanding is that the the exceptional divisor is set of points which are mapped to by $(0,0,0)$ during the blow up, so were looking for solutions of $x^2(z_0^2+y_0+xy_0^3)=0$ where $x=y=z=0$, but wouldn't that just be the plane $(0,y_0,z_0)$? At this point I'm not sure how to proceed as I don't know if this is actually the correct exceptional divisor.

If anyone could give a general explication of how to find exceptional divisors or show how to fully resolve this example and find all exceptional divisors and how they intersect that would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: At least for the sloppiest among us, the exceptional divisor is indeed just the "thing defined by the monomial that factors out" after plugging in the equations of the blowup. The exceptional divisor of the blowup of a smooth point in a threefold (i.e. the origin in $\mathbb A^3$ as here) is $\mathbb P^2$, and the plane $(0,y_0,z_0)$ is one of the affine patches of this $\mathbb P^2$. To obtain the exceptional divisor on the blown up singular surface, we intersect this plane defined by $x=0$ with the proper transform $z_0^2 + y_0 + xy_0^3=0$ to obtain the conic $z_0^2 + y_0=0$.

Comment: @TabesBridges Ok thanks that makes sense, though I made a typo the actual surface I wanted to blow up was $z^2+y(x^2+y^2)$ which I guess now would give the exceptional divisor being the $y_0$ axes when $x_0=1$. And for $y_0=1$ we would get the exceptional divisor being the $x_0$ axes. Now to draw the graph of the exceptional divisors we would need to find their intersection which I don't understand how to do since each one lies in a different affine chart so how do they intersect? Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: These are all just lying in a single $\mathbb P^2$, so it's a matter of piecing that together. My computation says that you just get $z_0^2 = 0$ in all charts, so that your exceptional divisor is just that line with multiplicity $2$. What you now need to do is check your proper transform. Usually with these kinds of things you have to blow up multiple times, and what you should probably find is that the singular point still meets the exceptional divisor so that as you continue to blow up, you get a connected tree of rational curves.

Comment: Ok I'm still not sure I understand if we blow up at $(0,0,0)$ and don't separate it into affine charts we get a variety in $\mathbb{A}^3 \times \mathbb{P}^2$ which will have an exceptional divisor in $\mathbb{P}^2$ then if its still singular we blow up again with $[x_1,y_1,z_1]$ but after this 2nd blowup what does the space look like is it now $\mathbb{A}^3 \times \mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^2$? So are we looking for intersections in the surface in variables $(x,y,z,x_0:y_0:z_0,x_1:y_1:z_1)$ defined by the original equation and all the blow up equations $x_iy_j=x_jy_i$ , ... @TabesBridges

Comment: That's correct. It is admittedly a huge mess...

Comment: Great that makes a lot of sense now, cheers for your help. @TabesBridges

Comment: And if you haven't seen them, I would suggest Googling and looking over Miles Reid's notes on Du Val singularities for some help with working out examples.

Comment: I think I know the notes your talking about, they're on my list of stuff to read so I'll move them to the top of that list. @TabesBridges